# Better coding style in Java? Implementing relative time

Tags: java, syntax, coding-style, code-formatting

I have no formal training in programming and I don't know what is proper way of coding, but this is something that is really scratching my eye. I developer here something to get relative time, right now it's something like this.

```
if (minutes < 59) {
    if (minutes == 1) {
        relativeTifmeString = minutesString+" minute ago";
    } else {
        relativeTifmeString = minutesString+" minutes ago";
    }
} else {        
    if (hours < 23) {
            if (hours == 1) {
                relativeTifmeString = hourstring+" hour ago";
            } else {
                relativeTifmeString = hourstring+" hours ago";
            }
        } else {
            if (days == 1) {
                relativeTifmeString = dayString+" day ago";
            } else {
                relativeTifmeString = dayString+" days ago";
            }
    }
}
```

But this is really ugly, even thouhg it works? Is it possible to write it down in more beautiful/more effective way? Or how would you do it?

Comment: Please elaborate what is "beautiful"..

Comment: I wouldn't call this ugly. It certainly has a lot of braces and it looks a bit repetitive, but at least it's clear what it does. Often I see people so afraid of a bit of repetition in their code, that they start to write really convoluted solutions that aren't easy on the eyes at all. Sometimes it's best to write code the "dumb way".

Comment: Better for the eye and to read the code?

Comment: Why are you making those "dayString" etc in advance? Better make them only if needed.

Comment: Look at handling plurals using i18n: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.se.

Comment: @Kayaman Nah, it's pretty ugly, and the shared functionality is hidden behind that repetition.

Answer (score 2):

I'd end up with something like this, depending on what you're actually doing and why. Pseudo-code:

```
public String getRelativeTimeString() {
    return getAppropriateString(minutes, hours days) + " ago";
}

public String getAppropriateString(minutes, hours, days) {
    if (minutes < 59) {
        return pluralize(minuteString + " minute", minutes);
    } 

    if (hours < 23) {
        return pluralize(hourstring + " hour", hours);
    } 

    return pluralize(dayString + " day", days);
}

public String pluralize(String s, int count) {
    return count > 1 ? s + "s" : s;
}
```

Comment: Exactly right, create a pluralize function and utilize the ternary operator :)

Answer (score 0):

> Wrap it in a function which  **returns a String**.

```
public String getTime(){

   String outputString = "";

   // Minutes
   if(condition for minutes is true){
       outputString = "SomeText";
       return outputString ;
   }

   // Hours
   if(condition for hours is true){
       outputString = "SomeText";
       return outputString ;
   }

   // Days
   if(condition for daysis true){
       outputString = "SomeText";
       return outputString ;
   }
}
```

Comment: multiple returns is not good style

Comment: @nachokk I totally agree with you, but with the conditions that the OP had, was not sure of any better way. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I was focusing more on readability of the code and keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we knew how minutes and hours are being populated first.  For example, could days be 2, hours be 11, and minutes be 23 all at the same time?  If so, the If statement:

```
if (minutes < 59) {
if (minutes == 1) {
    relativeTimeString = minutesString+" minute ago";
} else {
    relativeTimeString = minutesString+" minutit ago";
}
```

would be the only if statement the condition would be entering even though it would have been more than 2 days ago.